# fullcalendar time limit rendering in AgendaView

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

With Fullcalendar's **agendaView**, is it possible to show a limit on time (displayed on the left of the grid)? Example, by default the time displayed is from 12:00 am  to 11:59 pm; now say I want to display from 10:30 am - 9:00 pm. Would this use case be possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {  
      agendaDay:  {
        minTime: '10:30',
        maxTime: '21:00'
    }
}
```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/maxTime/

The docs don't mention that, but you can even set non-standard minTime/maxTime like '36:00' to see the whole day today plus half day from tomorrow.